# Common query to insert records for existing IDs

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert new record for all the existing IDs in the table. For example,

[image: Insert new record]

I need to insert new record "B" to all the IDs (1, 2, 3). Likewise, whenever insert new record, it should be applied to all the IDs.

[image: Expected output]

I can generate script for all IDs, but if any new ID inserted I need to generate query for that.

> Is there any simple way (common query) to insert record for all IDs
>   without using ID?

Comment: can you show the expected output after inserting `B` ?

Comment: Updated expected output...

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(id int)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM [yourtable]

INSERT INTO [yourtable] (ID,Name)
SELECT id,'B'
FROM @temp
```

or simply

```
INSERT INTO [yourtable] (ID,Name)
SELECT DISTINCT  id,'B'
FROM [yourtable]
```

Does this help you?

Comment: If I insert record "C", then what will happen? It will insert 6 records with "C"... right? I just need to insert 3 records...

Comment: then you can use the first method

Comment: DISTINCT is missed in that query... Yes, we can do with that... I am asking for any other way to get it done...

Answer (score 0):

1) Select all the ID and the new Name you want to insert with it.

2) Put that query in an INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, Name) SELECT DISTINCT ID, 'B' FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Get all the unique IDs and insert new value to all IDs... I can do it as per your query... But what is my question is, Is there any single query to insert? `eg: INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (?,'B')`, where ? is unique IDs..